# Как расположить элементы на одном уровне по высоте независимо от содержимого в колонках?

Tags: css, flexbox, позиционирование, центрирование

Как расположить ссылки (отмечены красным) на одном уровне по высоте независимо от содержимого в колонках?
Должно быть как на картинке ниже, flex-end не помогает, потому что смещается ссылка, если увеличить текст, к тому же на скрине она не к концу прилегает.

```
<div class="tiles">
<div class="container tl">
  <div class="tile chart">
    <h3>SEO Optimized</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galand scrambled it to make</p>
    <a href="#" class="plus">+</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tile pad"><h3>SEO Optimized</h3>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing adustry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, xt ext ever since the 1500s,ver since the 1500s,when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to makemy text ever since the 1500</p></div>
  <div class="tile cloud"><h3>SEO Optimized</h3>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make</p>
  <a href="#" class="plus"></a></div>
</div>
```

```
.tl{
     m-w:1200px;
     display: flex;
     color: #000;
     margin-top: 70px;
     justify-content: space-evenly;
     padding-left: 18px;
   /* padding-top: 30px; */
}
.tile{
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.plus{
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

[мой код на codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wbRQYr)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: position:absolute

Comment: пример на всякий случай https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GaPPWO

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```css
.tl {
  m-w: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 70px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding-left: 18px;
  /* padding-top: 30px; */
}

.tile {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.plus {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 900;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  color: white;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 4px 13px;
}

.container>.tile {
  position: relative;
}

.tile.chart,
.tile.cloud {
  background-color: #2d5f3a;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tile.pad {
  background-color: #f74c54;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="container tl">
    <div class="tile chart">
      <h3>SEO Optimized</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galand scrambled it to make</p>
      <a href="#" class="plus">+</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tile pad">
      <h3>SEO Optimized</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing adustry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, xt ext ever since the 1500s,ver since the 1500s,when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to makemy text ever since the 1500</p>
      <a href="#" class="plus">+</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tile cloud">
      <h3>SEO Optimized</h3>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make</p>
      <a href="#" class="plus">+</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```